# NSSwapInt from byte array

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to implement a function that will read from a byte array (which is a char* in my code) a 32bit int stored with different endianness. I was suggested to use NSSwapInt, but I'm clueless on how to go about it. Could anyone show me a snippet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heres a short example:

```
unsigned char bytes[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 };
int intData = *((int *)bytes);
int reverseData = NSSwapInt(intData);

NSLog(@"integer:%d", intData); 
NSLog(@"bytes:%08x", intData); 
NSLog(@"reverse integer: %d", reverseData);
NSLog(@"reverse bytes: %08x", reverseData);
```

The output will be:

```
integer:33619968
bytes:02010000
reverse integer: 258
reverse bytes: 00000102
```

As mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains),

> Swaps the bytes of iv and returns the resulting value. Bytes are swapped from each low-order position to the corresponding high-order position and vice versa. For example, if the bytes of inv are numbered from 1 to 4, this function swaps bytes 1 and 4, and bytes 2 and 3.

There's also a NSSwapShort and NSSwapLongLong.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Am I at risk if my array is longer than 4 bytes? Should I copy into a temporary buffer?

Comment: There are Long and LongLong versions, too

Answer (score 1):

There is a *potential* of a data misalignment exception if you solve this problem by using integer pointers - e.g. some architectures require 32-bit values to be at addresses which are multiples of 2 or 4 bytes. The ARM architecture used by the iPhone et al. may throw an exception in this case, but I've no iOS device handy to test whether it does.

A safe way to do this which will never throw any misalignment exceptions is to assemble the integer directly:

```
int32_t bytes2int(unsigned char *b)
{
   int32_t i;

   i = b[0] | b[1] << 8 | b[2] << 16 | b[3] << 24;  // little-endian, or
   i = b[3] | b[2] << 8 | b[1] << 16 | b[0] << 24;  // big-endian (pick one)

   return i;
}
```

You can pass this any byte pointer and it will assemble 4 bytes to make a 32-bit int. You can extend the idea to 64-bit integers if required.